# Makefile for merging ROOT files with "hadd"

Tags: makefile, root-framework

I am currently writing a Makefile that has several nearly identical rules/recipes to merge `.root` files using `hadd`. Is there a good way to condense these into fewer rules? I'm not sure how useful `%` can be for the cases `data[4-6].done` since the numbers 4-6 do not match the 1-4 in the directory path.

Many Thanks

```
[Makefile]

DIR=/hdfs/store/user/$(USER)

DATA.root : data1.done data2.done data3.done data4.done data5.done data6.done
    hadd DATA.root $(addsuffix .root,$(basename $^))
    rm $(addsuffix .root,$(basename $^))
    rm $^

data1.done :
    hadd data1.root $(DIR)/de2012A_loose2Aug-DATA/1/*.root
    touch data1.done

data2.done :
    hadd data2.root $(DIR)/de2012A_loose2Aug-DATA/2/*.root
    touch data2.done

data3.done :
    hadd data3.root $(DIR)/de2012B_loose2Aug-DATA/1/*.root
    touch data3.done

data4.done :
    hadd data4.root $(DIR)/de2012B_loose2Aug-DATA/2/*.root
    touch data4.done

data5.done :
    hadd data5.root $(DIR)/de2012B_loose2Aug-DATA/3/*.root
    touch data5.done

data6.done :
    hadd data6.root $(DIR)/de2012B_loose2Aug-DATA/4/*.root
    touch data6.done
```

Comment: Is that `data[1-6].done` pseudo-code, or does it actually work?

Comment: And are you sure you want to use those `data*.done` files? I don't see that they're necessary.

Comment: The purpose of the `data*.done` files is to ensure that `hadd` finishes before allowing the dependent rule to execute. `hadd` produces a file before it finishes, so the `DATA.root` rule would run prematurely.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. If `hadd` doesn't spawn child processes, then Make won't execute the `DATA.root` rule until `hadd` is done. And if it does, then `data*.done` won't save you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a crack at it, but you might reconsider your design.

```
DIR=/hdfs/store/user/$(USER)

DATA.root : data[1-6].done
    hadd DATA.root $(^:.done=.root)
    rm $(^:.done=.root)
    rm $^

data1.done data2.done : PATHLEFT=A
data3.done data4.done data5.done data6.done : PATHLEFT=B
data1.done : PATHRIGHT=1
data2.done : PATHRIGHT=2
data3.done : PATHRIGHT=1
data4.done : PATHRIGHT=2
data5.done : PATHRIGHT=3
data6.done : PATHRIGHT=4

data%.done : 
    hadd data1.root $(DIR)/de2012$(PATHLEFT)_loose2Aug-DATA/$(PATHRIGHT)/*.root
    touch $@
```

(Yes, I know, I could squeeze two or three more lines out, but I don't want to make it too cryptic.)